# TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined with pg-promise insertion

Tags: javascript

I have a simple class with a method that makes inserting data easier. I'm using `pg-promise` library to talk to database.

```
class C_SQL
{
    insert_text(text)
    {
        var time_now = new Date();

        return
        db.none(
            `INSERT INTO notes(\
                    id,\
                    date,\
                    text,\
                )
            VALUES (\
                (SELECT max(id) from notes)+1\,
                '${time_now.setFullYear(time_now.getFullYear() + 1) ? time_now : ``}',\
                ${text}\
            );`
        );
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use it like so:

```
var one = new C_SQL();
one.insert_text("inserted from a program")
    .then(() => console.log("Inserted"))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I must be doing something wrong, causing `insert_text` method to not return any promise. I'm getting the following error:

```
    .then(() => console.log("Inserted"))
    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
...
```

Trying generic `db.query(...)` produces the same issue. However in other parts of my code (in a similar class inside method), `db.query("SELECT...` works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript has a misfeature called [“automatic semicolon insertion”](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion) that’s turning this:

```
return
db.none(
    …
);
```

into this:

```
return;
db.none(
    …
);
```

You can fix it by not having a newline directly after `return`, and prevent it by running a linter – [ESLint](http://eslint.org/), for example – as part of your development process.

```
return db.none(
    …
);
```

Comment: That was it, thanks! I have been poking around for an hour trying to debug.